# PHP regular expression to match pattern \\domain\username

Tags: php, regex, string, match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match a string in the format of \domain\username using PHP and I can't get it to return the matched pieces in an array.

```
$username = "\\domain\jason";    
$login = preg_match_all("/^\\\\[a-z0-9\-]+\\[a-z0-9\-]+$/i", $username, $found);
    var_dump($found);
    array
      0 => 
        array
          empty
```

I tested my regular expession with an online tester and it matched the string perfectly.

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the fields are separated by a `\` just do this:

```
$username = '\\domain\jason';

$arr = explode('\\', $username);

echo $arr[1]; // domain
echo $arr[2]; // jason
```

**[ [DEMO](http://viper-7.com/YGFOx0) ]**

Comment: split() is deprecated, and completely un-needed here. An explode() would do fine.

Comment: @TML sorry forgot, yes explode would do it.

Comment: I thought split is aliased to explode

Comment: @joeframbach `split()` takes a regex as it's delimiter, `explode()` takes a string. `split()` was deprecated in favor of `preg_split()` in PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$username = "\\domain\jason";
if (preg_match_all('~\\\\?(\w+)~', $username, $arr))
   print_r($arr[1]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain
    [1] => jason
)
```